# Profiler cannot detect my device

Tags: android, android-profiler

I am using Android Studio 3.1.3 and deploying my app on Lenovo Phab PB1-770M, (Android 5.1.1, API 22). Since yesterday, Android profiler has stopped detecting my device and even though I am able to run and debug on my device using AS, Profiler just cannot detect that the device is connected.

[image: Android profiler screenshot]

However, I am able to deploy my code and debug it on my device, as you can see in the logcat 
[image]

Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: I am surprised what makes people downvote questions. Either you know the answer and can help, or you can't. What makes you downvote this question which is asking an actual issue whose solution I did not find anywhere on the internet.

Comment: did you ever work this out? Have just had this happen on AS 3.5.

Comment: @DavidTchepak I don't remember. I don't think I did though.

Answer (score 5):

try `adb root` and `adb remount`, I just resolve the problem in this way.

Comment: its work for me

Answer (score 3):

```
adb root
adb remount
```

Sometimes `adb remount` fails.

Apply the commands below to make it work.

```
adb disable-verity
adb reboot
adb root
adb remount
```

Answer (score 1):

Re-attach USB again. or

Invalidate Caches/Restart (File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart -> Invalidate and Restart).

Comment: Yup! Disconnecting and connecting the device again worked for me. In addition to this, I have connected my device over wifi network so I disconnected that device by using command `adb disconnect <device-ip>` and then connecting it again with `adb connect <device-ip>`

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but maybe someone will encounter this problem on Android Studio 3.5 or newer.

In addition to the mentioned @CodeWithVikas answer, clearing of the LogCat helped me.

Answer (score 0):

press in the first image where it says [DISCONNECTED] and search for your app package

Comment: It does not even find my connected device, forget about my app package.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this guide solved anyone's problem cause it was my solution.

First go to Build -> Edit Build Types...

then in the build types tab, as below click on debug and then ok.

[image]

it will let you have a profiler for your app.